# Фоновое определение занятого места на диске

Tags: linux

Запустите задачу определения количества занятого места на диске в фоновом режиме с записью ответа файл (задача должна запуститься в фоновом режиме;)

Linux mint

Как реализовать?

Answer (score 2):

Ээээммм... Я тут случайно увидел ваш ответ в очереди правок.

Зачем вам этот бесконечный цикл? А если не дай бог нагрузка на сервере и df будет выполняться дольше секунды?

Можно же было просто

```
df -h > 1.txt &
```

И есть ещё nohup - отличная штука, когда ssh работает нестабильно, а команда долгая.

Почитайте по теме: https://habr.com/company/ruvds/blog/326826/

Comment: Зачем nohup, когда screen есть? ;)

Comment: @0andriy сам я предпочитаю tmux (не будем спорить о вкусах), но видел много людей, кто вообще не слышал и не понимает зачем.

Answer (score 0):

```
while true; do df -h >> 1.txt; sleep 1; done&
```